# GetUsers in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I am trying to get the list of users in ADO using .NET clients. I am referring to this git repository:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Quickstarts/dotnet/GraphQuickStarts/Samples/EnumerateUsers.cs

I tried same thing but still it shows error that GetUsersAsync needs assembly reference. I have tried all the references. I am getting GetUserAsync but that is for one user. I need to fetch all the users.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `GetUsersAsync`, please use `ListUsersAsync`:

```
PagedGraphUsers users = graphClient.ListUsersAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This is awesome. But I wanted the license details too in this something like- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1

Comment: In your example, you are using [Users - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) api, not [User Entitlements - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) api. If you want to use User Entitlements - List api, you need to install package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.MemberEntitlementManagement.WebApi` and get users entitlements using `GetUserEntitlementsAsync.`

Comment: I understand that i need to get entitlements and I have used MemberEntitlementManagement.webapi. I am using like this:
MemberEntitlementManagementHttpClient memberEntitlementManagementHttpClient = connection.GetClient<MemberEntitlementManagementHttpClient>();
But I don't see GetUserEntitlementsAsync. I can see GetUserEntitlementAsync which fetches details for sinle user. Do you have a one line sample?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it. I was using MemberEntitlementManagement but it was a preview version so GetUserEntitlementsAsync was not getting listed. I changed updated it to a stable version and worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the following two code samples i'm returning the users' emails. You can use Azure DevOps' userentitlements to return the information you need like the license details.

[image: license details]

**SDK**

```
    //string organization = ...
    //string userName = ...  
    //string pat = ...
    List<string> users = new List<string>();
    var uri = new Uri($"https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}");
    var credentials = new VssBasicCredential(userName, pat);
    using (var connection = new VssConnection(uri, credentials))
    using (var client = connection.GetClient<MemberEntitlementManagementHttpClient>())
    {
        string continuationToken = null;
        do
        {
            var data = await client.SearchUserEntitlementsAsync(continuationToken);
            continuationToken = data.ContinuationToken;
            foreach (var member in data.Members)
            {
                string email = member.User.MailAddress.ToLower();
                users.Add(email);
            }
        }
        while (continuationToken != null);
    }
```

**Rest API**

```
    //string organization = ...
    // HttpClient client = ...
    List<string> users = new List<string>();
    string baseUrl = $"https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=6-preview.3";
    string url = baseUrl;
    string continuationToken = string.Empty;
    do
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            dynamic data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
            foreach (var member in data.members)
            {
                users.Add(member.user.mailAddress.ToString());
            }
            continuationToken = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data.continuationToken.ToString());
            url = baseUrl + "&continuationToken=" + continuationToken;
        }
    }
    while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(continuationToken));
```